# How to add style to the div that is followed by a div of particular class using css?

Tags: html, css

i want to add the margin property to the div of class="first" that is followed by a div of class="note".

I have tried below

```css
div.first + div.note {
      margin: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="root">
    <div class="first">
        first
    </div>
    <div class="note">
        note
    </div>
</div>
```

But this adds margin to note div but wanted it for first div.
How could i change it to add it to the div with class first. could someone help with this. thanks.

Comment: there is no previous sibling selector

Comment: could it be done by javascript if not css.

Comment: yes, but you would have to have a go at doing it yourself and if you get stuck, then ask a question showing your attempt - if you make no attempt then your question is off topic

Comment: or you could swap the order of your divs in your html and use css flex to swap them back when displayed

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36118012/12166116